# Gamescene.sks running it in iphone 6 white outline around bottom right corner

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit

[image: white outline bottom right corner]

There is a white outline that I do not know where it's coming from, I have the fps and node number , how do I eliminate the white sihlouette around the Gamescene.sks?  I've set the size to the standard 768 x 1024 .
**Xcode 9.2 beta**

Comment: There could be so many problems with this.  Since you are seeing white and not black, I can only guess that your view heirarchy has a main UIView and a child that is SKView

Comment: I actually noticed that some of my objects have a green outline as well, do you think that's because of the collision bitmask?

Comment: are you showing physics?  Would look like `view.showPhysics = true`

Comment: Hmm don't see it, i'm using SKSpriteNode

Comment: Yes I saw it! that was it - thank you @Knight0fDragon